# How to get all elements of any table sqlserver vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get all elements of a table using this script, but when I click ok it doesn't show anything... I don't know why.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd13 As New SqlCommand
    Dim da13 As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt13 As New DataTable
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=driving_school;Integrated Security=true")

    dt13.Clear()
    Dim StrsTables As String = "Table_1"
    Dim b As String = "SELECT c.name 'ColumnName', t.name + CASE WHEN t.name IN ('char', 'varchar','nchar','nvarchar') THEN '('+ CASE WHEN c.max_length=-1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CASE WHEN t.name IN ('nchar','nvarchar') THEN c.max_length/2 ELSE c.max_length END ) END +')' WHEN t.name IN ('decimal','numeric') THEN '('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),c.precision)+ ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),c.Scale)+')' ELSE '' END as ""Data_Type"", convert(nvarchar,replace((replace(c.is_nullable,'0','NOT NULL')),'1','NULL')) as 'Nulle',c.is_identity as 'Inc' , ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'PK' FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(1)"
    cmd13 = New SqlCommand(b, cn)
    da13 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd13)
    da13.Fill(dt13)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = da13
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably your SQL then. Are there any errors? Does that SQL run in SSMS

Comment: This is a fine example of why you should give your variables meaningful names.  You have mistakenly (at least I hope it's a mistake) assigned `da13` to the `DataSource` of your grid instead of `dt13`.  Mind you, that should have thrown an exception at run time if it got that far. I can't see how that code could execute and not throw an exception of some sort.

Comment: yes yes this is it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @jmcilhinney said:

> This is a fine example of why you should give your variables
> meaningful names

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=driving_school;Integrated Security=true")

    dataTable.Clear()
    Dim StrsTables As String = "Table_1"
    Dim query As String = "SELECT c.name 'ColumnName', t.name + CASE WHEN t.name IN ('char', 'varchar','nchar','nvarchar') THEN '('+ CASE WHEN c.max_length=-1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CASE WHEN t.name IN ('nchar','nvarchar') THEN c.max_length/2 ELSE c.max_length END ) END +')' WHEN t.name IN ('decimal','numeric') THEN '('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),c.precision)+ ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),c.Scale)+')' ELSE '' END as ""Data_Type"", convert(nvarchar,replace((replace(c.is_nullable,'0','NOT NULL')),'1','NULL')) as 'Nulle',c.is_identity as 'Inc' , ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'PK' FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(1)"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
    sqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable
End Sub
```